# Implementing `concat` for `Cons a`

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm looking at an exercise to implement `instance Monad []`. However, I'd like to implement `Monad Cons` given the following definition:

`data Cons a = Cons a (Cons a) | Empty`

I attempted to implement the equivalent of `concat`, but I called it `flatten`:

```
flatten :: Cons (Cons a) -> Cons a
flatten Empty                  = Empty
flatten (Cons c@(Cons _ _) xs) = ...
```

But then I got confused about how `[a]` maps to `Cons a (Cons a)`.

Please give me a hint to write the rest of `flatten`.

Comment: So what might be tripping you up could be the double-use of the word Cons; try `data List a = Cons a (List a) | Empty`. For example if you wrote the expression `[a]` that would now be written as `Cons a Empty`; `[a, b]` as `Cons a (Cons b Empty)`, and so on. You can do this without other primitives like `foldr` and `++` by simply walking both the list and the list-in-a-list at one pattern match and emitting each `x` you see: `flatten xss = case xss of Empty -> Empty; Cons Empty xss' -> flatten xss'; Cons (Cons x xs) xss' -> Cons x (flatten (Cons xs xss'))`.

Answer (score 4):

It is actually pretty simple. The `concat` function is usually defined as follows:

```
concat :: [[a]] -> [a]
concat = foldr (++) []

foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr _ a []     = a
foldr f a (x:xs) = f x (foldr f a xs)

(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
[]     ++ ys = ys
(x:xs) ++ ys = x : xs ++ ys
```

Let's call the `Cons` version of these functions `flatten`, `reduceR` and `append` respectively:

```
flatten :: Cons (Cons a) -> Cons a
flatten = reduceR append Empty

reduceR :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Cons a -> b
reduceR _ a Empty       = a
reduceR f a (Cons x xs) = f x (reduceR f a xs)

append :: Cons a -> Cons a -> Cons a
append Empty       ys = ys
append (Cons x xs) ys = Cons x (append xs ys)
```

Unlike @jamshidh I used implemented a right fold instead of a left fold because the way `(++)` is implemented, `a ++ (b ++ c)` is less computationally expensive than `(a ++ b) ++ c`.

Now we can make `Cons` an instance of `Monad` as follows:

```
instance Functor Cons where
    fmap _ Empty       = Empty
    fmap f (Cons x xs) = Cons (f x) (fmap f xs)

instance Monad Cons where
    return a = Cons a Empty
    m >>= f = flatten (map f m)
```

Simple. Try making `Cons` an instance of `Applicative` and `Alternative` next.

Answer (score 3):

Just to keep my brain from exploding, I would first define a function that combines two `Cons a` items

```
consPlus::Cons a->Cons a->Cons a
consPlus Empty x = x
consPlus (Cons x rest) y = Cons x (consPlus rest y)
```

Then I would define a `Cons a` version of `foldl`

```
consFoldl::(b->a->b)->b->Cons a->b
consFoldl f init Empty = init
consFoldl f init (Cons x rest) = consFoldl f (f init x) rest
```

then finally extend it to concat in the obvious way

```
consConcat = consFoldl consPlus Empty
```

---

Another brain-explosion-avoidance-technique would be to define `Cons a` like this

```
data Cons a = a ::: Cons a | Empty
infixr 8 :::
```

The difference is just syntax, but is is way easier to read this

```
(1:::2:::Empty):::(3:::Empty):::Empty
```

than this

```
Cons (Cons 1 (Cons 2 Empty)) (Cons (Cons 3 Empty) Empty)
```

Comment: @dfeuer- Helps partially, but I still find it hard to read because a. it is words, and b. you can't get rid of the extra parens (I think....  is there a way to do `infixr` on `Cons`?)

Comment: Yes, `infixr 5 'Cons'`, but with backticks instead of single quotes.

Comment: @dfeuer- Hey, cool, I like it!  I learned something today (.... although I still prefer the `(:::)` operator here :) )

Comment: @dfeuer You can type backticks in comments by escaping them using backslashes: `infixr 5 \`Cons\``.